# Autohide blank columns after filter

Tags: excel, vba

Would it be possible to create Excel VBA that auto hides columns that are blank past the first row after a filter is applied in the first column?

Comment: To answer the question you've posted, Yes it is possible. Welcome to SO. Visit the [help site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a question here to get the best results

Comment: Since I simply wanted a yes or no answer I feel like I asked this correctly. 

"Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague"

I simply didn't want to waste my time trying to do something that was not possible. So, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. However, SO is not the place for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

After filtering, you can check which rows are still visible with: `Range.EntireRow.Hidden`.  Iterate through these rows to see if they're blank, and then hide the column by setting `Range.EntireColumn.Hidden` to `True`.